# Hide payment method if specific variation is in Checkout Page | Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using this code on my WordPress website to hide the payment gateway when a particular Product variation is selected. However, as soon as I insert the code, WordPress displays a Critical error from the backend. Kindly help me with how to use this code on my website?

Product attribute: Personalization Required
Variables: Yes| No

I want to achieve if someone selects a 'Yes' variation then COD options get disabled on the checkout page. Alternatively, if they select 'No' then only the cod option is available.

Product Page URL: https://savvyandgroovy.com/product/prashant/

**This is what I am currently using:**

```
add_filter(‘woocommerce_available_payment_gateways’, ‘conditional_payment_gateways’, 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways($available_gateways)
{
  $in_cart=false;
  foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key=>$values)
  {
    // See if there is an attribute called ‘pa_size’ in the cart
    // Replace with whatever attribute you want
    if(array_key_exists(‘personalization-required’, (array)$values[‘data’]->get_attributes()))
    {
      foreach($values[‘data’]->get_attributes() as $attribute=>$variation) ;
      // Replace ‘small’ with your value.
      if($variation==‘Yes’) $in_cart=true; //edited
    }
  }
  if($in_cart)
    unset($available_gateways[‘cod’]); // unset ‘cod’

  return $available_gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working properly but it is giving error because of quotes which you are using. I have updated it as bellow:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    $in_cart = false;
    
    if ( !empty(WC()->cart) ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        // See if there is an attribute called ‘pa_size’ in the cart
        // Replace with whatever attribute you want
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($values['data']->get_attributes());
        //echo '</pre>';
        if (array_key_exists('personalization-required', (array) $values['data']->get_attributes() ) ) {
            foreach ($values['data']->get_attributes() as $attribute => $variation);
                // Replace ‘small’ with your value.
                // if ($variation == 'No') $in_cart = true; //edited
                if ($variation == 'Yes') {
                    $in_cart = true; //edited
                    // unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset ‘cod’
                }
            }
        }
    
        if ( $in_cart )
            unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset ‘cod’
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

**I want to achieve if someone selects a 'NO' variation then cod options get disabled on the checkout page Alternatively, if they select 'YES' then only the cod option is available.**

This will not work reverse in your code because you have written `if ($variation == ‘Yes’) $in_cart = true; //edited` so you need to update it also. So that also I have updated in above code.

Comment: A big thanks for a prompt reply. However, there is some confusion. 

1) I wanna disable COD on Yes. 
2) On no, all payment gateway shall show/display.

Comment: @ShwetaArya Please clear my doubts so I can help you further:

1) If yes - all other payment gateways display and COD disabled. Is this correct?
2) If no - including COD all payment gateways display. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, You understood it very right. Your understanding is very correct...

Comment: Okay so I have updated my answer. Please check if this helps you. I have tested it and it is working as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much. Where can we follow you on social Media?

Comment: Hey, code worked like a charm but it is creating a fatal error in WordPress. Any idea on how can we work around it?

Comment: I have updated code. Can you check if it removes error?

Comment: Unfortunately, this creates codes everywhere. You may check https://savvyandgroovy.com/product/prashant/

There are codes on page, cart n checkout. 
quick, view: https://ibb.co/6vXV89R

Answer (score 1):

The code above is not quite full since the OP wants to hide payment gateways in both scenarios so i just tweak the 1st answer a bit.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;
    $hide_cod = $hide_rest = false;
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if($cart_item["variation"]["attribute_pa_personalization-required"] === 'no') {
            $hide_rest = true;
            
        }

        if($cart_item["variation"]["attribute_pa_personalization-required"] === 'yes') {
            $hide_cod = true;
        }
    }
    
    if($hide_cod) {
        unset($available_gateways['cod']);
    } 
    if($hide_rest) {
        unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
        unset($available_gateways['cheque']);
        unset($available_gateways['ppcp-gateway']);
        //etc
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

**Keep in mind that if you add both variations in cart youll be left with no payment method.**

Comment: A big thanks for a prompt reply. However, there is some confusion. 

1) I wanna disable COD on Yes. 
2) On no, all payment gateway shall show/display.

Comment: Well since your original question is - "I want to achieve if someone selects a 'Yes' variation then COD options get disabled on the checkout page. Alternatively, if they select 'No' then only the cod option is available." I have edited my answer. If you dont want to hide any payment gateway just comment them or delete em.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in the question previously. I commented the //if($hide_rest) {
  //      unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
    //    unset($available_gateways['cheque']);
      //  unset($available_gateways['ppcp-gateway']);
        //etc

Even then the code does not seem to work.

Comment: Make sure you are looking for the same variation or change to your needs. Its tested on fresh wordpress intall with default woocommerce install and twentytwentyone theme. Works without problems. If you get any errors or something give some more info.

Comment: You may check savvyandgroovy.com/product/prashant

This is the product. I am using the same variation only. I don't see any error message as such. It is just that COD is not hidden on choosing a yes.

Comment: Well you can see from my screenshot that cod is not there with selected Yes option - https://prnt.sc/1qy977f