# Hide payment method if specific variation in Cart/Checkout | Woocommerce + Product Add-ons Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/ plugin for adding the product addons on a whole category(on all its products). I have many options as addons on all particular category products like for Stitching, Matching addons, matching borders etc. as shown in the image below
[image: None]

I want to hide Cash on Delivery(COD) payment gateway if Matching Addons and Stitching are selected and are there in the cart/checkout.

Now, I have been facing difficulty finding any specific variation id to implement a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68994195/9513172

Since in the cart/checkout, it shows with a dt class tag as shown in the image below:[image: nothing]

Here test product link: [here](https://www.bhaiyajiandsons.com/shop/do-not-delete-test-product/)

Answer (score 0):

After giving few hours to solve this problem, I came up with this solution for now:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'xyz_conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function xyz_conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    
    $in_cart = false;

    if ( !empty(WC()->cart) ) {
        $cart_item = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        $addons = array_values($cart_item)[0]['addons'];
        foreach ( $addons as $subKey => $value ) {
            if ($addons[$subKey]['name'] == "Stitching"){
                $in_cart = true;
            }
        }
    }
        
    if ( $in_cart )
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset ‘cod’
    return $available_gateways;
}
```